# oracle datetime field spark fails read with precision error

Tags: python, apache-spark

I've been chasing this issue for a while and I'm out of options that I know. I am loading a parquet file that has rows like this:

```
RFS,FOI,1209591006000,64.0000,1209591007000,Y,1209591007000,04/30/2008 17:30:07,1209591007000,UPDATER
```

What is unhelpful, is spark is throwing an error telling me the precision for DecimalType is greater than 38 (it's limit). Here is the relevant stacktrace:

```
19/07/09 20:24:02 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 203, ip-10-230-246-236.ec2.internal, executor 1): org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: DecimalType can only support precision up to 38;
at org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType.<init>(DecimalType.scala:52)
```

Questions:
1) I don't understand what column could be throwing spark off, none seem even remotely close to the precision limits
2) How can I get spark to tell me more specifically which column it is failing for (or even better yet, which row?)?
3) I can't print the schema in spark because I can't even read in the file (stored in S3) because of this exception, so I'm unsure how to verify the schema is correct.
4) Is this an incorrect schema in the parquet file? Or is it a problem with the data?

Info:
- Spark is running as a glue job (Serverless) but I believe is on the latest version.
- parquet file is being generated by HVR and is parquet version v3 with no compression.

I've done some googling and people say you should manually specify the schema to control it but I can't in this instance because this is a large ETL process where we aren't always going to know the schema (we rely on the embedded schema in the parquet files and sparks read abilities).

Comment: does the executor node give better stderr? I would start with those logs  from your spark history of this job

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have posted the answer below about what it turned out to be.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an issue with the ingestion tool I used to land the files in S3. The fields that were causing problems were any columns that had a datatype of "number" on the oracle source. With this specific datatype and the specific ingestion tool we were using to land the parquet files in S3, it had the data correct but somehow the embedded parquet schema showed the field as a decimal(1000,4). Even though none of the values in that column had a precision greater than 4. The vender ended up issuing a fix and the datatype came through with the correct precision and spark stopped complaining.